# How to Copy a table from webpage source code using Excel vba which is a mouse over table on web page

Tags: excel, vba

I have requirement in my project to copy a table from web page to excel. Here the table appears on web page only when we mouse overs a word.

How can I copy the specific table required to an excel using VBA. Is it possible to copy from source code?

Comment: No  URL, no code.... too broad....

Answer (score 0):

You mean the table is not visible unless the mouse hovers a specific part of the page? Then yes, you should be able to use VBA to extract it from the page's source, as it is most probably embedded in it. You can verify it by Inspecting that text or looking at the source.